# JSON Schema to POJO - Enum as a separate java file

Tags: java, json, enums, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

**Type.json (Enum)**

```
{
    "type" : "string",
    "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "type resource",
    "name": "type resource",
    "description": "List of types",
    "id" : "type:v1",
    "enum" : 
        [
        "ACC1",
        "ACC2"
        ]
}
```

**Pojo1.json**

```
"properties":{
            "type" : {
                "$ref" : "Type.json"
            },
}
```

**Pojo2.json**

```
"properties":{
            "type" : {
                "$ref" : "Type.json"
            },
}
```

Instead of creating a separate java file for enum, it creates a enum inside one of the POJOs and this inner public enum is referred by the other POJO.

**Pojo2.java**

```
private com.Pojo1.Type type;
```

How to create a separate java file for enum ? Thanks

Comment: You are using jsonschema2pojo right? How do you invoke it, do you use command line, maven plugin or something else?

Comment: command line. that in turn uses jsonschema2pojo maven plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like creating enums as separate classes is supported in jsonschema2pojo as an option.

The generation of enums is carried out by [org.jsonschema2pojo.rules.EnumRule](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/blob/master/jsonschema2pojo-core/src/main/java/org/jsonschema2pojo/rules/EnumRule.java)

The javadoc of which states:

> A Java {@link Enum} is created, with constants for each of the enum
>   values present in the schema. The enum name is derived from the nodeName,
>   and the enum type itself is created as an inner class of the owning type.
>   In the rare case that no owning type exists (the enum is the root of the
>   schema), then the enum becomes a public class in its own right.

Sounds like you'll need to raise a feature request

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing the post there was already a feature available in the jsonschema2pojo library. During my investigations I came over this post and was not pleased with the answer that it is not possible to reference a generated class or enum. So I digged a little deeper in the [documentation](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/pull/287), which did give me some additional extension properties to the usual json schema specification (javaTypes, javaInterfaces, javaEnumNames, javaJsonView, javaName). The documentation for the extension property javaType states:

> jsonschema2pojo supports an extension property 'javaType' that applies to schemas and allows you to specify a fully qualified name for your generated Java type.

Given this knowledge your example needs to be rewritten like that:

**Type.json (Enum)**

```
{
    "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type" : "string",
    "title": "type resource",
    "name": "type resource",
    "description": "List of types",
    "id" : "type:v1",
    "type_enum": {
      "javaType" : "com.mycompany.TypeEnum",
      "$ref": "TypeEnum.json#/definitions/type_enum"
    }
}
```

We now replace your enum definition by a reference *$ref* including a dedicated package path and class name for the *javaType*.
The referenced json schema for the according enum in your type class would then just look like that:

**TypeEnum.json (Enum)**

```
 {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "type_enum": {
      "enum": [
        "ACC1",
        "ACC2"
      ],
      "description": "All values for the enum in the type class."
    }
  }
}
```

The Pojo definintions Pojo1 and Pojo2 are left untouched. You can even reference the enum in other classes like so:

**TypeV1_1.json (Enum)**

```
{
    "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type" : "string",
    "title": "type version 1.1 resource",
    "name": "type version 1.1 resource",
    "description": "List of version 1.1 types",
    "id" : "type:v1_1",
    "type_enum": {
      "javaType" : "com.mycompany.TypeEnum",
      "$ref": "TypeEnum.json#/definitions/type_enum"
    }
}
```

leaving you always with only one generated enum for your defined javaType.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible I did it in this way:

```
 "atributes": {
  "description": "Additional message attributes",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "action": {
      "description": "Action to do over document",
      "$ref" : "Action.json#"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "examples": "{\"action\":\"UPSERT\"}"
}
```

and action enum:

```
{

      "title": "Action",
      "description": "Action description",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "BATCH",
        "DELETE",
        "UNSUPPORTED"
      ],
      "javaEnumNames": [
        "UPSERT",
        "DELETE",
        "UNSUPPORTED"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for me, could you share an example of it working please?

Comment: Kindly share your files with me.